# plotting the proportion of occurrence of a categorical variable in a sample

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a variable in a dataset called "gender" that can take values "m" or "f". I want to see the proportion of "m" in the sample. I have tried something similar to the following, but this code actually works to account for two variables and not for one. Any ideas?

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = gender,fill = gender)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

Thank you

Comment: `this code actually works to account for two variables and not for one.` I don't understand what you mean. It would be more helpful if you were to provide with an example of your data set using `dput()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the proportions of each of your categories than I would suggest to compute the proportions manually instead of relying on `position="fill"`.

One approach would be to compute the props on the fly using `after_stat` and the `count`s computed by `geom_bar` under the hood like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count)))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

A second approach would be to aggregate your data before passing it to ggplot like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars |> 
  count(cyl) |> 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = pct)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]