# How to make a line and dot chart to represent frequencies of categorical variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

I would like to make a chart like in this picture instead of a barplot to represent frequencies of several categorical variables. [image: the graph I want to make]

This is a snippet of my data for the variable of interest:

```
c("Mixed", "Mixed", "Administrative", "Administrative", "Biophysical", 
"Biophysical", "Administrative", "Administrative", "Administrative", 
"Administrative", "Administrative")
```

And I have produced the following code inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713499/plotting-the-proportion-of-occurrence-of-a-categorical-variable-in-a-sample) and despite I do not get any error message, there is no plot drawn. I restarted R several times but it does not seem to be an issue. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
hnvf9 <- hnvdata %>%
  select(Boundary)%>%
  mutate(Boundary1 = as.factor(Boundary))%>%
  count(Boundary1)%>%
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n))%>%
  ggplot(aes(Boundary1, pct)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = Boundary1, ymin = 0, ymax = 100,color = "lightgray", lwd = 1)) +
  geom_point(colour="red", size = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a lollipop chart. You can create one in ggplot as follows

```r
x <- c("Mixed", "Mixed", "Administrative", "Administrative", "Biophysical", 
  "Biophysical", "Administrative", "Administrative", "Administrative", 
  "Administrative", "Administrative")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(table(x)/length(x)), aes(Freq, x)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = Freq)) +
  geom_point(color = "#2aadab", size = 5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = 'gray50') +
  scale_x_continuous('Percent', breaks = 0:4 * 0.25, limits = c(0, 1),
                     labels = ~100*.x) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
```

[image]